# Is it possible to create a route mapping in ASP.Net Core 2.1 without AddMvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm completely new to ASP.NET Core, i searched a lot but still get confused about routing in Core 2.1.

So, i created a sample project chosing API as template and the VS created something like following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

But i dont need of all features offered by the MVC, because my project does not use views.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can simply use `services.AddMvcCore`, and then only add services that you actually need. The `app.UseMvc` part just drops in the middleware that's been register, so you don't need to do anything special there. Despite the name, it's not just MVC-specific, so you still need the call in some form.

Comment: I'd encourage you to go look at the source for each of these. There you'll be able to see each call is actually doing, i.e. the services `AddMvc` registers vs `AddMvcCore`, etc. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

Comment: @ChrisPratt tks for the suggestion. I looked the AddMvc and i have found the things that do not need (razor views and so on).

Answer (score 4):

Yes . Although we often use routing with MVC , [Routing](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing)  is a  project that has no dependencies on [MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc).

When working together with ASP.NET Core , Routing works as RouterMiddleware behind the scene . If you don't want to MVC , simply build a router :

```
private IRouter BuildRouter(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{
    var builder = new RouteBuilder(applicationBuilder);

    // use middlewares to configure a route
    builder.MapMiddlewareGet("/api/hello", appBuilder => {
        appBuilder.Use(async (context,next) => {
            context.Response.Headers["H1"] = "Hello1";
            await next();
        });
        appBuilder.Use(async (context,next) => {
            context.Response.Headers["H2"] = "Hello2";
            await next();
        });
        appBuilder.Run(async (context) => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello,world");
        });

    });

    builder.MapMiddlewarePost("/api/hello", appBuilder => {
        // ...
    });

    // ....

    return builder.Build();
}
```

And register the router middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseRouter(BuildRouter(app));
}
```

Here's a screenshot when it works :

[image]

Comment: Niceeee! Dint know this was possible.

Comment: It is work with a default route just like in the classic WebAPIConfig?

`config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: @MickMarosky .  The WebApi template use MVC with default routes . However , as you described above ,  if you choose to use `Routing` without `Mvc` , how can the `Routing` realize there's a controller or action ?  Are you trying to create a WebApi  project without views ?

Comment: @itminus yes my project will not use views.

Comment: @MickMarosky I'm wondering why not use the WebApi template if you want the default router behavior that dispatches request to MVC actions ?

Comment: @itminus the AddMvc() adds a lot of things that i will not use:
`(builder.PartManager);

    builder.AddFormatterMappings();
    builder.AddViews();
    builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
    builder.AddCacheTagHelper();`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1:

```
var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app, trackPackageRouteHandler);

routeBuilder.MapGet("hello/{name}", context => {
    var name = context.GetRouteValue("name");
    return context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hi, {name}!"); });            

var routes = routeBuilder.Build(); app.UseRouter(routes);
```

Or if you want to implement it as custom middleware and you need only basic routing:

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
public class Startup
{
    private static void HandleMapTest1(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Map Test 1");
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/map1", HandleMapTest1);

        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from non-Map delegate. <p>");
        });
    }
}
```

Or if you need more routing features, see itmius' answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377807/2085502

Answer (score 0):

Solved, using the following Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvcCore().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddCors();
}

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Thanks for all that tried to help me!